# What is the role of solution folder in an visual studio solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I created a new visual studio solution with a new project.

So my folder structure is:

```
D:\
├── MyNewProject (this is the solution folder containing the solution (.sln) file and project folder)
│   ├── MyNewProject.sln
|   ├── MyNewProject/ (this is the project folder containing project (.proj/.csproj) file, and other files/folders related to the project)
|   |   ├── MyNewProject.proj (or .cspro)
|   |   ├── files
|   |   ├── folders
```

In the sln file or the proj file there is no mention of the solution folder. So, what is the role of solution folder in an visual studio solution? Is it just a container with no relevance to the sln and proj files? Which means it can be renamed or taken out (while keeping its contents) with out any concern on dependencies?

Comment: You can have multiple projects in a solution so it's a container.  I would not advise renaming it though.

Comment: You can have a look at [http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/VSSolutionFolders.aspx](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/VSSolutionFolders.aspx). It mainly describes the function of  visual studio solution folder.

Comment: Appreciate if you can add it as answer so will be helpful for everyone

Comment: Ok, I have done it. You can mark it as answer by clicking “√”.

Comment: It is an option, you don't like it much when a solution only has a single project.  But highly sensible when it has more.  File > New > Project, note the "Create directory for solution" checkbox.